# Camera with different mobile device

Tags: android

I am having problems with opening camera intent on different devices.

I can start the app I wrote on a Xiaomi device with no problem, but when starting the app on other devices, there is a problem.

Here is my code. Sorry that there are no log files to show.

```
private void startCamera() {
    // 使用android內建api
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Case = 10; // camera
    // 檔案名稱使用時間來記錄
    SimpleDateFormat sDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    date = sDateFormat.format(new java.util.Date());
    // 強制轉型.jpg
    date = date + ".jpg";
    // 檔案存放地方 還有檔案名稱
    tmpFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/DCIM/100ANDRO", date);
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(tmpFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
            .parse("file://" + tmpFile)));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    /**
     * Camera
     */
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 2) {
        // 利用BitmapFactory去取得剛拍照的圖像
        // 檔案名稱使用時間來記錄
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.getPath());
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I have no idea where the bug is.

Comment: what problem is there? Any stack trace?

Comment: i use different mobile to open my app~ one is working , but other one is shows problem , is that different devices got different setting ? about the camera. sorry that the other device no have driver to install and debug in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If your App can't open camera, maybe you need to install a camera App to respond the Intent.

These is another serious issue in your code. You load an image from camera directly.

this is your code:**Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.getPath());**

Usually the image is too big to load without scaling.It will cause an **OOM exception**.If your App
crashed by an OOM exception.Try the method below:

```
public static Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Activity a, String path) {
    Display display = a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    float destWidth = display.getWidth();
    float destHeight = display.getHeight();

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    float srcWidth = options.outWidth;
    float srcHeight = options.outHeight;

    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (srcHeight > destHeight || srcWidth > destWidth) {
        if (srcWidth > srcHeight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round(srcHeight / destHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round(srcWidth / destWidth);
        }
    }

    options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    return bitmap ;
}
```

**Bitmap bmp = getScaledBitmap(YourActivity, imageUri.getPath());**

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i have try before , just still have problem in different devices, thanks a lot :)

Comment: hi friend , i found the problem ~ just i also dont know why the problem is , maybe the version problem

Answer (score 0):

`private void startCamera() {
        // 使用android內建api
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Case = 10; // camera
        // 檔案名稱使用時間來記錄
        SimpleDateFormat sDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        date = sDateFormat.format(new java.util.Date());
        // 強制轉型.jpg
        date = date + ".jpg";
        // 檔案存放地方 還有檔案名稱
        tmpFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/DCIM/100ANDRO", date);
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(tmpFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
//      this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
//              .parse("file://" + tmpFile)));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);`

Comment: i close the sendBroadcast , then i works in other phone ~
thanks @zz-m